# Assigning a range of values to a variable in tikz

Tags: latex, tikz

I would like to assign a range of values to a variable in LaTeX to be used in a loop within a tikzpicture environment.

In the below code I would like to replace these lines

```latex
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {1, 3, 5, 7}
    \foreach \y in {2, ..., 5}{
```

with something like

```latex
first_range = {1, 3, 5, 7}
second_range = {2, ..., 5}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in first_range
    \foreach \y in second_range{
```

A complete runnable code section is below:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {1, 3, 5, 7}
    \foreach \y in {2, ..., 5}{
        \ifthenelse{\(\x=1 \OR \x=7\) \AND \y = 3}{
            %\filldraw[fill=white] (\x, \y) circle (0.2);
            \node[] at (\x, \y) {\vdots};
        }{
            \filldraw[fill=red] (\x, \y) circle (0.2);      
        }   
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the list in a macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\def\first{1, 3, 5, 7}
\def\second{2, ..., 5} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in \first
    \foreach \y in \second {
        \ifthenelse{\(\x=1 \OR \x=7\) \AND \y = 3}{
            %\filldraw[fill=white] (\x, \y) circle (0.2);
            \node[] at (\x, \y) {\vdots};
        }{
            \filldraw[fill=red] (\x, \y) circle (0.2);      
        }   
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```